# Java - KeyListener does not work, but ActionListener does

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

When click MenuItem NewGame. It works, but press F2 it doesn't

```
mntmNewGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(contentPane,"Do you want to play new game ?", "Message!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        }
    });

    mntmNewGame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyListener(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F2)
            {
                int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(contentPane,"Do you want to play new game ?", "Message!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is why you should always use `@Override` when overriding methods... `KeyAdapter` doesn't have a `keyListener` method - it has `keyPressed`, `keyReleased` and `keyTyped`. For example, you might want:

```
mntmNewGame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F2) {
            int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                contentPane,
                "Do you want to play new game ?",
                "Message!",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            // Use n, presumably...
        }
    }
});
```

With the `@Override` annotation, if you make a typo, the compiler will spot that you're *trying* to override something, but not actually doing so - so you get a compile-time error, rather than just a method that's never called.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using something `JMenuItem`?  In which case you should using [`JMenuItem#setAccelerator(KeyStroke)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke))

```
mntmNewGame.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0));
```

This will trigger the `ActionListener`

See [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details

If not, then you should be making use of the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`.  `KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component is focusable AND has focus